# How to edit the default domain policy?

Tags: windows, powershell

New to PowerShell here and I am being asked at the powershell prompt to execute the command to increase the minimum password length to 9 character. To get to this point I had to get the default domain password policy using the Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy command in power shell to bring up the parameters that I can alter. From there I used the Set-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy command, and after that I'm pretty much lost. This is probably my second time using powershell so I'm not advanced at all.

[image: I was able to actually pull the commands I need to alter but after that I did not know what to do.]

Comment: Just set the new value - PowerShell doesn't care about the old value: `-MinPasswordLength 9`

Answer (score 0):

The command is:

```
Set-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy -MinPasswordLength 9
```